# Prove that there exist uncountable family of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ which is linearly (totally) ordered by relation of inclusion.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that there exist uncountable family of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ which is linearly (totally) ordered by realtion of inclusion.

I do not know how to prove it. Actually I cannot concieve that such family of set can be uncountable. I would be thankful for help

Comment: @MeesdeVries : actually, many exist. **Hint**: $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, and dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Max, I am not sure how to use density here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint:* Fix a bijection $f \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb Q$. For each $x \in \mathbb R$ let
$$
C_x := \{ q \in \mathbb Q \mid q \le x \},
$$
where $\le$ is the natural order of $\mathbb R$. Show that $(\{ C_x \mid x \in \mathbb R \}; \subseteq )$ is a linear order, that $C_x \neq C_y$ for $x \neq y$ and conclude, by pulling the $C_x$ back via $f$ $(\dagger)$, that there is an uncountable family $\{ D_x \mid x \in \mathbb R \}$ of subsets $D_x \subseteq \mathbb N$ which is also linearly ordered by $\subseteq$.

$(\dagger)$ I'm intentionally vague here.

Comment: Ok, I see that $\{C_x,\subseteq\}$ is linearly ordered. Now, because $f$ is bijection, I can define $D_x=f^{-1}(C_x)$. Now this is totally ordered by relation of inclusion because of properties of bijection. Is it correct?

Comment: That's correct. However, since you don't seem to know (with certainty) that the linear order translates correctly via $f$, you should prove that.

Comment: To prove that, all I need to do is to take $x\leq y\in\mathbb{Q}$ and show that $D_x\subseteq D_y$?

Comment: Well, basically. Here are two remarks: First of all, $x,y$ are elements of $\mathbb R$ - not $\mathbb Q$. Secondly, you also need to prove that $x \neq y \implies D_x \neq D_y$.